# Can't install node package even though I'm not using a proxy

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi

I'm (very) new to nodejs and raspberry pi.
I'm trying to install the onoff package for a test project, following [this](http://thejackalofjavascript.com/raspberry-pi-node-js-led-emit-morse-code/) tutorial.
Everything works fine and I've set up a new node project using `npm init`.

Installing onoff (`npm install onoff`) however fails.
It says:

> npm ERR! network getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND npm ERR! network This is most
>
> likely not a problem with npm itself npm ERR! network and is related
>
> to network connectivity. npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind
>
> a proxy or have bad network settings. npm ERR! network  npm ERR!
>
> network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the npm ERR!
>
> network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

I've checked using `npm config get proxy`, this returns null so I don't think this is a proxy issue.

Anyone who can help me with this?

UPDATE:
`ping 74.125.224.72`returns "network is unreachable"

Comment: Let me ask the obvious, are you sure you are connected to internet? Try `ping google.com` to be sure...

Comment: I suppose I am... I put an ethernet cable in the raspberry pi, took it's IP address and connected to it via my computer, and then executed the command `npm install onoff`. Other installs (such as nodejs itself) did work without any problems. `ping google.com` however returns "unknown host google.com".

Comment: Well that depends on how you installed nodejs. :P Technically I can tell that your raspberry pi can't resolve DNS properly...

Comment: I installed nodejs using `$ wget http://node-arm.herokuapp.com/node_latest_armhf.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i node_latest_armhf.deb`. Don't know whether or not this is relevant, but installing forever using `sudo nom install forever`did work too...

Comment: Could it have something to do with the fact that I changed the IP to static?

Comment: Can you ping anything else what about google.com?

Comment: Couldn't ping anything. Ended up with reinstalling Rasbian, which solved the problem. Probably some IP misconfiguration. Thanks for the responses!